# ARC Semantic Issue - No Known Instance Method For Selector

Tags: ios, build, ionic3, orientation, selector

In an attempt to compile my iOS build, I get this error message. Anyone seen this before?

No known instance method for selector.

Answer (score 0):

It means a selector sent to an object cannot be handled because the object (or its super) doesn't have corresponding methods, and the message forwarding process failed to handle it. You should check your code according to the error message and make sure the callings are correct.